# Why is `res.sendFile` not doing anything? No errors, but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

For some reason res.sendFile in a post method isnt working at all. Like there is no error, but it isnt working. Let me show you the code

```
app.post('/login',(req, res) => {
  var password = req.body.password;
  //console.log(password) <- it logs it correctly
  
  if(password == 'hey'){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index2.html');
    res.end('yes')
  }else{
    res.end('no');
  }
 
});
```

I also tried changing the `path.resolve` for `path.join` and it's doing literally nothing. I added a `console.log('hey')` and it actually logs that. But it doesnt load the file html.

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var pass;
        $('#submit').click(function(){
          pass=$('#password').val();
          $.post("https://heresmypage.repl.co/login",{password: pass}, function(data){
            if(data === 'no'){
              alert("Password is not correct.");
            }
          });
        })
      })
    </script>
```

```
<input placeholder="Password" id="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></button>
```

Answers will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a few possible reasons:

1. You're ending the response before it has a chance to send the file by calling `end()`.

   When you use `sendFile()`, you don't call `end`; it does it for you. (This is true of most of the `Response` methods that send information — `send`, `json`, etc.)

   From the [`end` documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.end):

   > Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core, specifically the `response.end()` method of `http.ServerResponse`.
   >
   > Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, **instead** use methods such as `res.send()` and `res.json()`.

   *(my emphasis on "instead")*
2. There's a syntax error in the quoted code: You're missing a `)` on the `sendFile` call. That makes me think this isn't the code you're actually running (since you'd get an error), so perhaps the `sendFile` call isn't in the code you're actually running.
3. It may *be* sending the file, but the browser may be blocking access to it because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) if the page you're running that code on isn't from `https://heresmypage.repl.co`.

If I fix #1 and #2 and ensure that #3 doesn't apply, it works just fine; see `***` comments:

`index.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/login',(req, res) => {
    var password = req.body.password;
    //console.log(password) <- it logs it correctly
    
    if(password == 'hey'){
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index2.html'));
      // *** Added ) −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
      // *** Removed call to `res.end('yes');` here
    }else{
      res.end('no');
    }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"));
});
  
app.listen(3000);
```

`public/index.html`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>sendFile Question</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var pass;
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                pass = $('#password').val();
                $.post("/login", { password: pass }, function (data) {
                //     ^^^^^^^^−−−−−− removed the hardcoded path so the request is relative, to ensure
                // the SOP isn't the issue
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data === 'no') {
                        alert("Password is not correct.");
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
    <input placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></button>
</body>

</html>
```

`public/index2.html`:

```
<p>Hi</p>
```

Using the password `hey` gets me the contents of `index2.html` in `data`.

Comment: @Tiburoncin23 - We can only work with the information you give us in the question. I've added a couple of other notes as well.

Comment: @Tiburoncin23 - My guess is that the issue is #3 (or #2 and you're running a previous version of the code rather than the code you added `sendFile` to); your browser should be showing you an error related to it. I've updated the answer with a working example. I hope you figure it out!

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, it's weird because your code doesn't work with repl.it. Do you know why?

Comment: @Tiburoncin23 - No, I don't use repl.it. It works fine normally. repl.it must have some requirement (like specific port number / range, that sort of thing).