# sendFile function in express js is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

When i try t run this code, i don't get any error but i get a blank screen when i open loclhost.

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")

app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let fullpath = path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
    console.log(fullpath)
    res.sendFile(fullpath)
    console.log("File sent")
    res.end()
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

Im using linux, express version is 4.18.2, node version is 18.1.0

I executed the same code in a windows machine with same express version and it worked without any error. Maybe its something to do with linux compatibility or maybe how paths are different in windows and linux.

Things i have tried so far:

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")

app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let fullpath = path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
    res.sendFile(fullpath, { root: '/' })
    console.log("File sent")
    res.end()
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")

app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname)
    }
    let fileName = 'index.html'
    res.sendFile(fileName, options)
    console.log("File sent")
    res.end()
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

Comment: It seems like you didn't use a callback in `sendFile` and ended a response before the file was sent completely. Please look at the example of code here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-sendfile-function/ to get the idea how to do it. You need to call `res.end()` in the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer:

1. Remove **res.end();**
2. Try this code

```js
const express = require("express")
app = express()
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
   console.log("File sent")  
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate why res.end should not be used with sendFile or if u can link me up with an explanation, it will be very helpful. Thanks a lot nonetheless.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106066/20482928